# Branching process in varying environments

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions

Consider a model similar to the simple branching process except that individuals in the nth generation reproduce according to a reproduction law {$p_{nk}, k \geq 0$} with generating function $\phi_{n}(s)=\Sigma_{k}p_{nk}s^{k}$.  Let $Z_{n}$ be the number in the nth generation.

> 

a) Express the generating function

> $f_{n}(s)=Es^{Z_{n}}$
>
> in terms of $\phi_{k}(s), k\geq0$ where $\phi_0(s)=s$

b) Express $m_n=EZ_n$ in terms of $\mu_i, i\geq0$ where $\mu_i=\phi'_i(1)$

I don't really understand the problem. Is it that each generation splits into k offspring with probability $p_{nk}$, so the probability changes every generation?

Comment: Yes, this is the difference with the standard case.

Comment: Okay, so I'm still having trouble incorporating the changing probability into the offspring generating function

Answer (score 1):

This was asked some time ago, but I thought I would answer in case someone stumbles across this question while searching.

A way of doing these is to consider the conditional expectation on the population size of the $(n-1)^{th}$ generation.

First, let's write the number of offspring of the $i^{th}$ individual belonging to generation $n$ as $\xi^{(i)}_n$.

So, for (a):

$$f_n(s)=E[s^{Z_n}]=E[E[s^{Z_n}|Z_{n-1}]]=E[s^{\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}\xi^{(i)}_{n-1}}]\\
=E[E[s^{\xi_{n-1}^{(i)}}]^{Z_{n-1}}]=f_{n-1}(\phi_{n-1}(s))$$

where we have used the fact that $\xi_{n-1}^{(i)}$ are all independent and identically distributed. You can use this expression recursively to get the answer: $f_n(s)=\phi_{1}(\phi_2\dots\phi_{n-1}(s))$.

The way the question is written implies that perhaps they want you to take the answer from (a) and expand around $s=1$ to get the answer for (b), but you can just as easily derive it straight off:
$$E[Z_n]=E[E[Z_n|Z_{n-1}]]=E[\sum_{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}\xi_{n-1}^{(i)}]=\mu_{n-1}E[Z_{n-1}]\\
=\dots=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\mu_i$$

Note that $Z_0=1$ since we are told that $\phi_0(s)=s$.